# should we use exit in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, exit

According to C++ reference

> `exit` terminates the process normally, performing the regular cleanup
>   for terminating programs.
>
> Normal program termination performs the following (in the same order):
>   Objects associated with the current thread with thread storage
>   duration are destroyed (C++11 only). Objects with static storage
>   duration are destroyed (C++) and functions registered with atexit are
>   called. All C streams (open with functions in ) are closed
>   (and flushed, if buffered), and all files created with tmpfile are
>   removed. Control is returned to the host environment.
>
> Note that objects with automatic storage are not destroyed by calling
>   exit (C++).

as far as i know, when the process terminated, all the storage used by the process are reclaimed, so what's the impact that objects with automatic storage are not destroyed?

Comment: If an automatic scope guard variable is locking a mutex when the function calls `exit()`, that mutex won't be unlocked, and if any of the termination cleanup that is performed (for thread/static vars, atexit...) wants to lock the same mutex it may deadlock and prevent clean shutdown.

Comment: The standard is saying that everything the C++ runtime does is undone. It says nothing about your application. It does not ensure that **your application** cleans itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the fact not everything you might somehow take ownership of is listed in the standard as getting cleaned up.

For example, many programs and libraries do things like create lock files, start background processes, change system settings, and so on. These *may* be cleaned up by the OS if you call `exit`, but they aren't required to be. Failing to release these could have effects ranging from being unable to restart the program (typical of lock files) to total system failure (less likely, but possible in some cases).

*True, on-topic anecdote.* I used to use [OIS](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OIS), an input library, for my project. Every time I killed my program in the debugger, key repeat was broken system-wide, because OIS 'temporarily' disabled it in Linux. I fixed it by changing settings (and later dumping OIS entirely), but this illustrates very well the sort of issues you might run into calling `exit` before you have cleaned up your environment yourself.

Comment: i still have question: what can i use to stop a child process in C++ if exit is not a good option?

Comment: @xlnwel It's not that `exit` itself is bad, it's that depending on the cleanup behavior of `exit` is bad. As long as you clean up your resources before hand, it should be fine to `exit`, just like it would be fine to `return` from `main()`. So, feel free to use it, just as long as you make sure you're in a state to terminate. Usually, simply letting `main()` return is the preferred way to end programs, but I am not really familiar with how processes work, at least in general/cross platform, so if `exit` is useful in that case, use it - just be careful.

Answer (score 8):

If those destructors are not called, their side effects don't happen: Freeing resources in other processes, deleting temporary files outside that folder, flushing non-c stream files, etc etc etc

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you should preferably use [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler) rather than `exit` or `abort` to do an orderly fatal error exit, because code that you're using may have installed a [terminate handler](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler) to do critical cleanup.

The default `std::terminate` handler calls `abort`.

The stack is not unwound.

Re

> **”** what's the impact that objects with automatic storage are not destroyed?

Because destructors are not called, cleanup that they might do is not performed. For example, in Windows a console window might become unusable if it has a custom text buffer. Temporary files might be left on disk. Helper processes might not be shut down. And so on.

This must be weighted against the possibility of nasty things happening if general cleanup is attempted, e.g. because an assertion has fired, showing that some fundamental assumption about the process state doesn't hold.

Comment: thanks for answering, now that exit is not safe, and std::terminal as your described seems also not safe in C++, what can i use to stop a child process safely?

Comment: @xlnwel: To be completely safe you need some cooperation from the child process. E.g. that it checks a signal at short intervals. The C++ standard library doesn't provide any means (except the file system) of inter-process communication, so you'll probably need to use system specific functionality.